# Combining a datetime stamp with 2 other values to make 1 value

Tags: t-sql

New software that we have installed needs to have a specific id to be used as a refrence token to know where it left off in the sql database. Presently our other software that enters in data that i am refrencing is not giving no time `2013-05-20 00:00:00`. I would like to combine that date time stamp with my pipesize and period.

The data looks like this:

```
trandate = 2013-05-20 00:00:00   Pipesize = 30   Period = A
```

I need to have the data converted to look like `2013052000000030A` if it is possible or something close.

Answer (score 0):

I used the chart here to determine the correct format: w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp and the resulting sqlfiddle here. sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9654/3

Comment: I tried it like this, but I get an error message.  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), trandate, 101) + (pipesize + period) from BellandGasket  the error message is this: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '05/20/2013' to data type smallint.

Comment: Try it with just trandate.  You may want to try casting the pipesize + period to varchar.

Comment: I must be using the worthless gray matter in my head, but no matter what I have tried, I continue getting error messages when I try and join the datetime with my other two values. It is as if sql will not allow a date to manipulated with other values.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it correctly, but my data is screwed up in the fact it is lacking the correct time, and I cannot get the machine to add it. my original query:select trandate,pipesize,period from BellandGasket which gives me over 1153 rows of data in the order of |                         2013-05-20 00:00:00 30 A |
2013-05-20 00:00:00  8 A |
2013-05-20 00:00:00 30 B |
2013-05-20 00:00:00 12 B |
2013-05-20 00:00:00  8 B |
2013-05-20 00:00:00  6 B

Comment: I used the chart here to determine the correct format: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

and the resulting sqlfiddle here.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9654/3

Comment: Awesome Brent, you saved me tons of anguish:)